# Symlink to hidden file

Tags: data-synchronization, permission, folders, dropbox, symlink

I have 2 macs, and use Dropbox a lot. On my MacBook I have one folder synced with Dropbox (through a symlink, `ln -s ~/folder ~/Dropbox`) that is actually in my ~/Library directory, so it's hidden. It was a while ago, but I somehow got symlinks to work for it (I cant remember how now!). On my new iMac when I do it, the symlink file won't work, because it's linking to a file it doesn't have permission to see (needs sudo password).

Can anyone remind me how I did this (or show me a new way?).. Thanks

EDIT:
As pointed out, ~/Library is not hidden at all :) ... I have no idea why Dropbox won't upload it then. This happened before on my MacBook, and I can't remember what I did to fix it..

Comment: Why would you need sudo to access a file in `~/Library`? `~/Library`, by definition, is yours! Also, I can't use Dropbox to verify, but does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666071/how-do-i-symlink-the-contents-of-the-folder-without-including-the-actual-folder help out?

Comment: Yes that is very true, it doesn't need a password.. I don't know why it's not working on my iMac then, but I remember it wasn't working before on my MacBook, I just can't remember what I did. Dropbox refuses to upload it in anyway

Comment: What exactly is the file that does not work and what are its permissions

Comment: That's a good question.. On my MacBook it's 777 (drwxrwxrwx, yeah it's a directory), but I'll have to check it out on my iMac when I get home

Answer (score 1):

**Symlinks work for hidden files.**

When you

ln -s ~/hiddenfile  ~/folder/hiddenfile

there is a new file. But of course, you can't see it.

> If the files name begins with a point (".vimrc"), you can't see it
>   because finder doesn't show files with a point before the actual name.

Comment: Sorry, just realised its not a hidden file at all! Dropbox won't upload it for some reason